# A required resource is not available. Google cloud platform instance group

Tags: google-cloud-platform, resources

Resources being used: 1 vCPU, 3.75 GB, 1 K80 GPU. (for instance template)
Region: Asia east1.
Image: ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20190918. (for instance template)

I'm currently trying to create an instance group which spans across all 3 Asia-east zones. The creation fails and the error message given is "A required resource is not available.".

This message is very vague, is there any way to pinpoint what exactly is the cause of this error? If any further information is needed about my environment feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen similar errors cropping up when a quota is exceeded. My guess is your VMs are configured with external IPs and you have exceeded the number of external IPs allowed. It could be another quota as well. But I would suggest to try another region (us-east) or see if you can use VMs with no external IPs.

**Update**

Just noticed [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/) that K80 is not available in asia-east1-c. Try excluding that from the available zones of your instance group.

Comment: This worked for me, it was indeed the east1-c that was the problem. I removed it and things worked swimmingly

Comment: Good to know. Could you accept this answer in that case?

Answer (score 1):

if you got an error likes,

`Resource exhausted (HTTP 429): RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED`

it might be a credits issue in free trial account (started with $300)

when you tried to create an instance template on console page, also can show the estimated costs details

> 1 NVIDIA Tesla K80 GPU    $357.70/month

using [pricing calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) also you can check the credits before generating VMs.

in short, `get rids of GPU` or `ACTIVATE (upgrade your account)` would be helpful